# Dataset file (.xsd) not portable to VS 2019

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I'm working on a Visual Basic website project which works fine with Visual Studio 2015. I want to migrate it to VS 2019 version. After I opened it with VS 2019 i had a problem with the existing Datasets in the App_Code folder (.xsd file), no dataset is loaded...there comes an error saying that the value is null for the parametername: 'instance'. 
I also tried to add a new Dataset in the App_Code folder of the website and there is the same error, it looks like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: XSD is an XML document. Try to open that XSD using different editor to see whether this XSD has valid & wellformed markup. Did you migrate the project?

Comment: I know what XSD is and in my case it is wellformed. I think it's a bug. What do you mean with 'migrate' the project? Is there a special tool to migrate such projects?